# SBT config policy

Tags: scala, sbt, config

I'm working on Scala application, which is multi SBT project, so more SBT projects are included into root project as dependencies. I defined assemblyMergeStrategy like this:

```
`assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
     case PathList("src/main/resources", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.concat
     case PathList("reference.conf", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.concat
     case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
     case x => MergeStrategy.first
}`
```

But when config is loaded in child project (referenced inside root) it gets config from root project. What is recommended approach here? Should I maybe have only one config in root project so all dependent SBTs use it?

It would be beneficial to have config also in child projects for some testing purposes (standalone testing).

Thanks

Comment: Do you think you can share your whole build definition and perhaps the project structure?

Comment: Can't share it whole, but here's structure. I have 2 projects: projectA and projectB (both SBT). Now, project A has dependency on project B, like this (build.sbt in projectA): `"com.organization" %% "projectB" % "1.0"`. Both projects have config defined in main/resources/application.conf. I load config in each project using `com.typesafe.config.ConfigLoader.load`. When I log config in projectB, it turns out it got config from projectA application.conf. Is this enough info? Thanks for reply